# How can I convert a DataRow array to a DataTable without iteration?

Tags: c#-2.0

How can I convert a DataRow array to a DataTable without iteration?

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
dataTable = datarowarray.CopyToDataTable()
```

but ensure that `datarowarray` has `length > 1`, otherwise it will end up with unwanted exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can put an array of datarows to a datatable. You can import one row at a time using DataTable.ImportRow.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataRowArray)
{
   dataTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if there did exist a .NET framework function like

```
myDataTable.LoadRows(dataRowArray)
```

... all that would do is **hide** the iteration. The framework doesn't magically circumvent the iterative step (though in some cases it might be doing something gee-whiz smart to optimize it).

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use some bulk function of .NET framework for better performance.

```
DataTable dtDestination = new DataTable();  //your destination datatable

DataRow[] row;
row = dtMain.Select($"unit IN ({ filterString })"); //select data from main datatable

if (row.Length == 0)
{
    //handle if nothing match your select statment.
}
else
{
    //if have found row.
    dtDestination = row.CopyToDataTable();

    //or if your datatable is in DataSet and it's readonly.
    DataTable dtTemp = row.CopyToDataTable();
    dts.Tables["labofpatient"].Merge(dtTemp);
}
```

This is another way to import by loop, but it's slower and take time more than above function.

```
DataTable dtDestination = new DataTable();  //your destination datatable

DataRow[] row;
row = dtMain.Select($"unit IN ({ filterString })"); //select data from main datatable

foreach (DataRow dr in row)
{
    //you can choose one of the line of code below. It work on the same and no different in performance.
    dtDestination.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);   
    dtDestination.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

or by iterate value in datatable

```
DataTable dtDestination = new DataTable();  //your destination datatable
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.count; i++)
{
    dtDestination.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i]["col1"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["col2"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow[] dataRowArray = dt.Select("");
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in dataRowArray)
    {
        dataTable = dataTable.Clone();
        dataTable.ImportRow(row);
    }
```

Comment: The question asks for a solution that does not require iterating the `DataRow` array. Isn't your solution doing just that?

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.